# Editing a PSD using Gimp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I am totally new to this sort of thing.

I have been sent a template of a banner (see below) that I need to edit.  It is a simple four layer PSD file that I am going to open in Gimp as I can't justify the cost of Photoshop.

I just want to change the title and the picture of the music notation but, as a complete novice, I don't know where to start.

There are plenty of YouTube clips, but they deal with creation rather than editing.

I'm sure, to those in the know, what I am wanting to do is very straight forward.

Can anyone offer any help, using the simplest of language - assume you're talking to a three year old!!
[image: Example of Banner]

Comment: Without access to the PSD file, I can't tell what will be editable in GIMP or not. I can't tell you if the text will still be editable. You might need to create new layers, add new text, new layers, delete old layers, etc.

Comment: Look at it the other way... If you have the other musical score and the title, it will be a lot easier to create a Gimp image from scrach and cut/paste the trumpet icon

Comment: Gimp can open some PSD files. Have you tried to open it?

Comment: I can open the file in Gimp, no problem, and everything looks to be editable. However, I don't know where to start. How do I change the music notation for example? How do I change the text?